How to create build of Djnago web app rest api project, and what are the tools which can be possible use to create build?
I have developed Django web app in which rest Api's are written using Django rest framework. I have used visual studio code for coding. Now I want to create build of that project. I am new to build tools. Please list build tools which can be used for Django web app and guide in creating build.
I am new to Django as well as for build tools, I searched for build tools for Django, but I am not getting any relevant information, which I can understand and implement.

please shed some light - what you are considering as "build tools"?
